# How to get last IP address of DB update request ?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySql Database hosted in the cloud.

From an embedded device connected to the Internet network via an ISP  I write some values (coming from a sensor) in a table of this Database.

Is it possible to know the last IP address of the embedded device  by querying the DB ?

Answer (score 1):

No.

The file `access.log` contains connections, but that is not accessible via SQL.  (And your hosting service may not let you access that file.)